# reshape error - invalid 'row.names' length

Tags: r, reshape

I have the following database (in wide form), "st_all", where I have got two variables I wish to reshape ("P" and "PLC"). The id for the subjects is "g_id".

```
  g_id study condition sample PLC1 PLC2 PLC3 PLC4 PLC5 PLC6 PLC7 PLC8 PLC9 PLC10 P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10
1    1     1         1      1   20   20   20   50   50   20   30   20   50    50  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
2    2     1         1      1   60   70   50   70   60   60   60   70   60    50  1  2  1  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
3    3     1         1      1   80   50   55   58   70   50   80   80   60    65  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
4    4     1         1      1   89   51   59   62   72   60   86   80   61    54  1  1  2  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
5    5     1         1      1   90   50   60   70   80   50   90   80   60    50  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
6    6     1         1      1   95   50   60  100   95   60   50   60   60    55  1  2  2  1  2  2  1  1  1   1
```

To do so I ran the following code:

```
reshape(st_all,
idvar="g_id",
direction="long",
varying=list(c(5:14),c(15:24)), 
v.names=c("PLC","P")
)
```

and I get the following error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(d[, idvar], times[1L],  : 
invalid 'row.names' length
```

I have searched for an answer to this, but I do not find any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: I found the answer. I was using tbl format and that affected reshape function.

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the comments, you'll have problems with the `reshape` function when your data is a `tbl`.

Use `as.data.frame` first:

```
reshape(as.data.frame(st_all),
        idvar = "g_id",
        direction = "long",
        varying = list(c(5:14), c(15:24)), 
        v.names = c("PLC","P"))
```