# Is there a way to use reshape in tbl?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

In a previous question I had a problem using reshape:

[reshape error - invalid 'row.names' length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910592/reshape-error-invalid-row-names-length?noredirect=1#comment57557213_34910592)

After hours I realized it was because I was using tbl format and not data.frame. So to use reshape and keep the tbl environment I have to do:

```
mydata %>% as.data.frame %>% reshape(, ...) %>% as.tbl
```

So I wanted to know if there is another way to do so.

Comment: `reshape` is pretty slow and cumbersome. Have you checked out `reshape2` package or `tidyr`? They both should work properly.

Comment: This question must  be making Hadley squirm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More so that there's an answer than any other reason, here are four options to consider.

First, if you want to use `reshape` along with "dplyr", you'll have to make use of the `new.row.names` argument in `reshape`, and set them to a sequence of the number of rows you expect your reshaped dataset to have. The calculation is easy. Take the length of one batch of columns that are going from the wide form to the long form and multiply it by the number of rows in the original dataset.

This approach is sure to make Hadley squirm with displeasure, so use at your own risk.

```
mydf <- tbl_df(mydf)
class(mydf)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

mydf %>% 
  reshape(
    idvar="g_id",
    direction="long",
    varying=list(c(5:14),c(15:24)), 
    v.names=c("PLC","P"),
    new.row.names = seq_len(length(5:14) * nrow(mydf)))
```

Another approach that might make Hadley squirm, but a little bit less, would be to use `melt`, but the `melt` from "data.table", not from "reshape2". This would, of course, require you to convert your `tbl_df` to a `data.table`, so similar to your current approach, it requires another step.

```
library(data.table)
mydf %>%
  data.table %>%
  melt(measure.vars = patterns("PLC[0-9]+", "P[0-9]+"), 
       value.name = c("PLC", "P"))
```

Remaining within the Hadleyverse, you can try "tidyr" (as suggested by @DavidArenburg). It's not as pretty as he might have had in mind, because it requires first making a *very* long dataset and then re-widening it, unlike the `melt` approach above that does the not-so-long reshaping in one step.

```
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
  gather(var, val, starts_with("P")) %>%
  mutate(var = gsub("([A-Z]+)", "\\1_", var)) %>%  ## you can probably be clever and...
  separate(var, into = c("variable", "time")) %>%  ## come up with some fancier regex
  spread(variable, val)
```

Finally, there's also `merged.stack` from my "splitstackshape" package. With it, the approach would be like:

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(mydf, var.stubs = c("PLC", "P"), sep = "var.stubs")
```